# What do you refer to the feature for creating a category tree as?

Tags: hierarchy, categorization, structure, ux-writing

I'm designing a module for managers to perform administrative operations on fleets of buses they are assigned to. This includes the following parts,

**Manage buses:** add, remove, update bus details

**Manage fleet:** managers are assigned fleets of buses to manage.

The hierarchy of these fleets is complex and might have multiple levels.

e.g: fleets>teams>squads> this is basically the category tree that the buses will be put under

For this, I have created a UI that would allow users to build this hierarchy. once a fleet categorisation has been created, this structure will reflect in 'manage fleet' and buses will be put under various teams and squads. fleet managers will be assigned to these squads

My question is what is the best way to refer to this? would it be fleet structure, fleet categorization or any other term? I've yet to come across a feature like this.

it is a [image]

Comment: For UI terminology, it's usually best to ask your users how they talk about these things. Do you have access to users or any recorded user interviews you could refer to?

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Tree view](https://spectrum.adobe.com/page/tree-view/) in Adobe's Spectrum Design System and also in IBM's Carbon Design System ([work in progress](https://carbon-website-git-fork-designertyler-treeview03092020-c-54d75e.vercel.app/components/tree-view/usage/)), but probably goes by a few different names in other design systems.

It falls under the general category of designing for hierarchical information, and can be implemented in many forms including a tree view. It might also be called a tree list or node list as well.